# Use awk to output formated fields from each line

Tags: string, bash, unix, awk, sed

*Let **a** be a text file and **b** an unl file.*

In **a** I got separated data by spaces/tabs, and the last column got spaces.

I.E:

```
30714931330     1.0000  201608  10 X 10 S.A.
30594465497  E  0.0044  201608  1 SOYORRO S.A.
```

Here, "10 X 10 S.A." and "1 SOYORRO S.A." are the **last** column.

---

#### What I need to do is:

*Ouput some fields in each line from **a** to **b** in a way depending whether "E"(second column) is present or not, and each field should be separated by a semicolon ";" including the last one.*

The output format will be:

```
20160727;30714931330; ;1.0000;201608;
20160727;30594465497;E;0.0044;201608;
```

Where the *first field* is the date of issue in *YYYYMMDD* format(it is not in **a** file). How could I get it and put it here?

I worked with a few things and as a result I got:

```
awk '{if($2 == "E") {print $issueDate ";" $1 ";" "E;" $3 ";" $4 ";" > "b.unl"} else {print $issueDate ";" $1 ";" " ;" $2 ";" $3 ";" > "b.unl"}}' a.txt
```

Or

```
awk '{if($2 == "E") {print $issueDate ";" $1 ";" "E;" $3 ";" $4 ";"} else {print $issueDate ";" $1 ";" " ;" $2 ";" $3 ";"}' a > b
```

Is this a correct way to implement it?
Otherwise, How should I do this? Using sed would it help?

Thanks.

Comment: (a) There is more than one type of `UNL` file.  Which one are you using?  (b)  _"the first field is the date of issue...and I do not how to get it."_  You might need to provide a bit more information on that one.

Comment: wrt `separated data by spaces/tabs` - are the tabs and spaces just scattered randomly throughout your file or do they each occur at specific places in your file? Please edit your question to show in your sample input where the tabs (`<tab>`) and spaces (`<blank>`) occur as that has a big impact on the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `gawk` fixed field widths

```
$ awk -v OFS=';' -v d="$issueDate" 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="11 2 1 2 6 2 6 35"}
                                         {print d,$1,$3,$5,$7}' file

20160727;30714931330; ;1.0000;201608
20160727;30594465497;E;0.0044;201608
```

and pass the date as an `awk` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean that the first field of the output would be the current timestamp? If so, you can use functions `strftime()` and `systime()`.

I would use a guard expression instead of `if` and shift the fields to have only one print statement but this is just matter of style.

```
awk '
    $2 == "E" { e="E"; $2=$3 ; $3=$4; }
    { print strftime("%Y%m%d", systime()) ";" $1 ";" e ";" $2 ";" $3 ";"}
'
```

Answer (score 1):

Current time is always available from **date**(1).  Grab that once in the beginning.  To separate your output with ";", use the `OFS` variable:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "\t"
    "date +'%Y%m%d'" | getline date
}

{ e = " " }

$2 == "E" {
    e  = "E";
    $2 = $3;
    $3 = $4;
}

{
    OFS = ";"
    print date, $1, e, $2, $3 ";"
}
```

Invoke as:

```
$ awk -f E.awk E.txt 

20160816;30714931330; ;1.0000;201608;
20160816;30594465497;E;0.0044;201608;
```